# .htaccess URL Rewrite to affect Subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to achieve something with .**Htaccess** RewriteEngine.

I want to be able to controll subfolders via one single .Htaccess file, currently to get this working I have to have the same .Htaccess file in every folder & subfolder but it would be great to just have **one** in the ROOT folder to avoid copy-pasting.

Currenty my structure looks like this:

**ROOT**

- Images

  - 2012
    - January
    - February
    - ...
  - 2013
    - ...

  Other

  - Misc

Folders contain images that are accessed by `index.php?i=IMG_NAME` and by using the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.php?i=$1 [L]
```

I can use for example: `Images/2012/January/IMG_NAME` and it works fine to load the image. 
But as mentioned I have to have the above .Htaccess file in every folder & subfolder to get it working, otherwise I have to use `Images/2012/January/?i=IMG_NAME` are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this only skirttails the issue but if you don't have the actual url point to a real folder then you can run everything from the .htaccess file  from public_html.

So if you actually stored the images in /data/2012/January/*

Then had the url that is used by /Image/2012/January/IMG_NAME

Comment: That would actually work, that was my Original plan, not sure why i discarded that. 
But now I'm not sure how to write the code for the rewrite engine some that it "redirects" properly. WIll test and come back later

Comment: I'm going nuts over this, this is most likely so simple to do but I cant get a grasp of how the rewrite works at all...
How do I get all links that look like the following:

`*/Images/2012/January/IMG_NAME

*/Images/2013/January/IMG_NAME

*/Images/2012/January/Birthday_party/IMG_NAME

*/other/IMG_NAME` etc.

To all point to `*DATA/Images/2012/January/IMG_NAME`

but not showing the DATA folder in the name?
How to get this regardless of the depth of the subfolder structure etc? Thanks in advance, best regards

Comment: Sorry for the delay...hopefully you still get this...there are probably a lot of ways to do this but this is how I have done it in the past...the htaccess file has code like this....
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ ./rewrite.php

then the page that gets that data is just a script that handles the $_SERVER data and does whatever it wants...a lot of time its better to run from a db and just save the images as imageID.jpg then use the title db entry (or whatever) to determine what to use as a url